# BigQuery - Mixing data types in CASE WHEN error when using CONCAT?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So I'm trying to achieve something like this '2000 *' when the condition #1 is met. However, BigQuery gives back data type errors.
I assumed casting the SUM into a string should have resolved the data mixing type. What is happening?

Here is the error: `No matching signature for operator CASE; all THEN/ELSE arguments must be coercible to a common type but found: NUMERIC, STRING; actual argument types (WHEN THEN) ELSE: (BOOL STRING) (BOOL STRING) (BOOL STRING) NUMERIC at [3:3]`

Here is my code:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN (SUM(discount_amount)/SUM(grand_total) >= 0.05 AND SUM(discount_amount)/SUM(grand_total) < 0.1) THEN CONCAT(CAST(SUM(grand_total*rate) AS string), ' *')
    WHEN (SUM(discount_amount)/SUM(grand_total) >= 0.1
    AND SUM(discount_amount)/SUM(grand_total) < 0.12) THEN CONCAT(CAST(SUM(grand_total*rate) AS string), ' **')
    WHEN (SUM(discount_amount)/SUM(grand_total) >= 0.12) THEN CONCAT(CAST(SUM(grand_total*rate) AS string), ' ***')
  ELSE
  SUM(grand_total*rate)
END
  AS totalRevenue
FROM
  `focused-bridge-180706.mysql.glamira_sales_order` s
JOIN
  `focused-bridge-180706.mysql.glamira_directory_currency_rate` r
ON
  s.order_currency_code = r.currency_from
WHERE
  currency_to = 'EUR'
  AND status IN ('complete',
    'processing',
    'payment_accepted')
  AND DATE(created_at) = (CURRENT_DATE('Europe/Berlin') - 1)
  AND store_name LIKE '%AE'
```

Comment: Your ELSE returns a numerical, the WHEN...THEN return a string

Comment: In the else branch, concatenate with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

In this part:

```
  CASE
    WHEN (SUM(discount_amount)/SUM(grand_total) >= 0.05 AND SUM(discount_amount)/SUM(grand_total) < 0.1) THEN CONCAT(CAST(SUM(grand_total*rate) AS string), ' *')
    WHEN (SUM(discount_amount)/SUM(grand_total) >= 0.1
    AND SUM(discount_amount)/SUM(grand_total) < 0.12) THEN CONCAT(CAST(SUM(grand_total*rate) AS string), ' **')
    WHEN (SUM(discount_amount)/SUM(grand_total) >= 0.12) THEN CONCAT(CAST(SUM(grand_total*rate) AS string), ' ***')
  ELSE
  SUM(grand_total*rate)
END
```

`SUM(grand_total*rate)` is numeric where `CONCAT(CAST(SUM(grand_total*rate) AS string), ' **')` is a string, they need to be the same type.

Here is a fix:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN (SUM(discount_amount)/SUM(grand_total) >= 0.05 AND SUM(discount_amount)/SUM(grand_total) < 0.1) THEN CONCAT(CAST(SUM(grand_total*rate) AS string), ' *')
    WHEN (SUM(discount_amount)/SUM(grand_total) >= 0.1
    AND SUM(discount_amount)/SUM(grand_total) < 0.12) THEN CONCAT(CAST(SUM(grand_total*rate) AS string), ' **')
    WHEN (SUM(discount_amount)/SUM(grand_total) >= 0.12) THEN CONCAT(CAST(SUM(grand_total*rate) AS string), ' ***')
  ELSE
  CAST(SUM(grand_total*rate) AS string)
END
  AS totalRevenue
FROM
  `focused-bridge-180706.mysql.glamira_sales_order` s
JOIN
  `focused-bridge-180706.mysql.glamira_directory_currency_rate` r
ON
  s.order_currency_code = r.currency_from
WHERE
  currency_to = 'EUR'
  AND status IN ('complete',
    'processing',
    'payment_accepted')
  AND DATE(created_at) = (CURRENT_DATE('Europe/Berlin') - 1)
  AND store_name LIKE '%AE'
```